# Laravel with method equivalent in symfony2

Tags: php, database, symfony, laravel, doctrine-orm

I want fetch an entity with it's all relations all at once from database. In Laravel we have `with` method and we can use it like this:

entity:

```
 class Author extends Eloquent{
      public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('post');
      }
    }
```

usage:

```
Author::with('post')->get()
```

how can we do this in symfony2 and doctrine orm?

Comment: $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AuthorBundle:Author')->findAll()

Comment: check of lazy loading !!

Comment: he wants get all entities at once. It's not the solution. for what u said it have to query database for each related entity that u request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `fetch: EAGER` , for example u have Author in yml format:

```
App\MyBundle\Entity\Author:

  oneToMany:
    posts:
      targetEntity: Post
      mappedBy: author
      fetch: EAGER
```

Comment: With this solution eager load will be performed in every call in code (for example in authors listing!). You can (with fetch method lazy od extra lazy) build query with proper select and join instead. (ex.: select author, posts from YourBundle:Author author left join auhor.posts posts)